# how to make endless scrolling in recycler view with okhttp

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, okhttp

I am getting a json data using okhttp and showing it on recycler view.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .get()
        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        .build();

client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: ", e);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, final okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {
        final String data = response.body().string();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(data);

                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject Object = array.getJSONObject(i);

                        String name = Object.getString("displayname");

                        User user = new User(name);
                        userlist.add(user);

                        adapter = new dataadapter(mContext, userlist);
                        recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });


    }
});
```

I want that if user scroll to the last data in recycler view it should run again okhttp function and again connect to the server and get json file and add it to recyclerview.. ANd then user should get more data and it should keep scrolling.

Please help me i am facing this problem from many days and i am not getting any solution...

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Comment: I'm not an android developer but I have solved this problem in many web applications before. The design pattern is pretty simple, Load-Watch-Load. We load our initial data and then some we might make a second request to load more if there is a lot of data. Watch the user's position on the element, if they're near the end of the initially loaded data, make a request for more and load it into the ui.

Answer (score 0):

Please use Retrofit to pull data to/from API
just three steps to show data from server
1)Make model class according to json
2)call api with retrofit
3) after successful data retrieve pass it to recyclerview adapter
that's it

Comment: please follow this tutorial for your json data to recyclerview [https://velmm.com/retrofit-android-example-with-recyclerview/]